# I cannot open chrome on ubuntu server terminal

Tags: ubuntu, chrome

I installed google chrome on ubuntu terminal. After installation I issued 
commands chrome google-chrome and several others but the browser failed to show up. I just started learning ubuntu server terminal. I hope someone will help me with commands to open the chrome browser.

Comment: "Ubuntu terminal"? Are you running X Windows at all (a graphical desktop environment), or are you just working at the text console? What version of Ubuntu are you using and what package did you install?

Comment: I am using just the text console.

Comment: the version server ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I am new to ubuntu so I cannot remember the package.

Comment: I think it is google-chrome-stable

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to have some type of x-server running in order to use the application. If the machine you are executing the command on is local and you are logged directly into a terminal you will need to start your x-server first then open a terminal and run the command.

If you are using ssh to the machine that you are wanting to run the command on you will need to use -X to forward X before the application will open on the local machine you are using.

If you are running 100 percent in a terminal environment please look at lynx or links or links2 or elinks for cli only web browsers.

Comment: Thanks Larry G for your advice. I research on lynx, link2 or elinks.

Comment: @Djesu Please accept the answer if it satisfies you.